# python2.7:res_query.c:251:__libc_res_nquery:Assertion hp != hp2 failed

Tags: python, pycharm, centos6

[image]

When I run my Python Program in PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3 on the CentOS6.8,
I get the following error:

```
python2.7:res_query.c:251:__libc_res_nquery:Assertion hp != hp2 failed
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: What's your computer name (`hostname --fqdn`)? Also, what's the content of _/etc/resolv.conf_, _/etc/host.conf_? Since this doesn't seem to have anything to do with _Python_, what's your _libc_ version (`ldd --version` or `yum list glibc`)? Do you by any chance have a custom (modified and manually built) _libc_?

Comment: Thanks for your attention! I run the order line, I get the follow result:<br/>hostname: unknown host  <br/>The contentent of /etc/resolv.conf is <br/>#generated by NetworkManager  <br/> nameserver 61.134.1.4<br/>the content of /etc/host.conf is multi on <br/> The libc version is ldd(GNU libc)2.5@CristiFati

Comment: I took a look at [\[CentOS\]: libc rpm](http://vault.centos.org/6.6/updates/Source/SPackages/glibc-2.12-1.149.el6_6.7.src.rpm), and there is a file _res\_query.c_ having `assert (hp != hp2);` at line 251. But there's also a patch file (_glibc-rh804686.patch_), so I'm not sure how come you still have it. Did you try updating it (`yum update glibc`)? Also doesn't this error appear in other (network involving) apps?